# How best to implement an ID system on a functional collection

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In my project I'm using a `Seq[Drone]` to track drones in a world. It's a functional project, so both the world and the drones are values of case classes.

In the world's `process()` method, a new `World` instance is returned containing a transformed version of that sequence, and since it's unordered, there's no guarantee the drones come back in the same order. This was by design, for a preliminary implementation.

Now, though, it's time to implement an ID system so that they can be assigned actions individually (e.g. "d1 move to (4, 6)"). This means that the drones need to be stored in a way that preserves "order".

I've spent some time coming up with several approaches, but first, an establishment of how IDs actually *work*.

---

### ID Behaviour

- IDs are unique for all existing drones (drones that are in the world).
- When a drone expires, its ID is released.
- When a drone is added, it takes the lowest available ID. (This means IDs can be reused.)
- The `Drone` type does not have an ID - this is a concept only given meaning by a `World`.

### Option 1: Plain tuples

My `Seq[Drone]` would become a `Vector[(Int, Drone)]`. References to drones would change from `world.drones(n)` to `world.drones(n)._2`, which is bad for a whole bunch of reasons. ID would be accessible by `world.drones(n)._1`.

### Option 2: Type-aliased tuples

I'd add a typealias called `D` to `(Int, Drone)`, and change the `Seq[Drone]` to `Vector[D]`. This has similar issues to Option 1, I believe, though I don't have a lot of experience with typealiasing.

### Option 3: Case class

I'd make something like `case class D(id: Int, drone: Drone)` and turn `Seq[Drone]` into `Vector[D]` as Option 2. This has the advantage of providing nicer calls (`d.id` and `d.drone` rather than tuple element syntax), and can be used almost identically to tuples (`D(1, Drone())` vs `(1, Drone())` - a single character's difference).

---

My question is thus: **is Option 3 a suitable solution here?** If so, what kinds of problems might I run into in the future? (I envisage some work to tidy up calls, but other than that, nothing.) If not, what avenues can I explore to find something more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 3 of your options are almost the same.  A 2-tuple is really just a case class called `Tuple2`, where Scala adds some syntactic sugar so you can write `(a, b)` instead of `Tuple2(a,b)`.  So given those options, I would choose Option 3 because of the more descriptive methods names.  In fact for that reason tuples are often discouraged from being used.

However there is another possibility, use a `Map[Int, Drone]`.  This will give you some of the functionality you need out of the box (including fast lookup by id and uniqueness checks) and accomplish the same thing without needing to define your own new type.

For instance, you can define adding a drone as:

```
def addDrone(drones: Map[Int, Drone], newDrone : Drone): Map[Int, Drone] = {
  val id = (0 until drones.size).find(!drones.contains(_)).getOrElse(drones.size)
  drones + (id -> newDrone)
}
```

and releasing an id is as simple as removing it from the map.

Comment: I like this solution a lot! I had considered it, fleetingly, but forgot about it when I did this write-up. I think this will fit my use case, so I'll give it some more time and if nothing else comes up, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you ^_^